# grunt preprocess @include not working in jenkins build

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, gruntjs

I am using grunt-preprocess to include my code modules into main js file on build. the preprocess works fine when am running the build on my local. However, when the same is executed in my jenkins server (running on linux), the @include fails and replaces the @includes with not found statements as below.

preprocess include statement

```
    // @include Falcon.helper.js
// @include Falcon.config.js
```

After running the grunt build in jenkins server. i get this

```
app/core/Falcon.helper.js not found
app/core/Falcon.config.js not found
```

Below is the preprocess task configuration

```
module.exports = function (grunt, options) {
return {
        core: {
            src: '<%= config.lib %>/core/falcon.js',
            dest: '.tmp/js/falcon.core.js'
        }
    };
```

}

My falcon.js and falcon.helper.js,falcon.config.js are in the same core folder under app.

```
app/core/falcon.js
app/core/falcon.helper.js
app/core/falcon.config.js
```

My guess

- Mapping problem
- @include using Falcon.helper.js but file name is falcon.helper.js

PS: This approach was taken from the backbone.marionette.js build file. [Backbone.marionette core js](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/build/marionette.core.js)